# How can I make the `PlaceAutocompleteFragment` resolved?

Tags: android, google-places-api

**How can I make the `PlaceAutocompleteFragment` resolved?**

I am trying to use the new `PlaceAutocompleteFragment`. I try to use the following code:

```
<fragment
  android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
  />
```

*This code sample is just a copy. It is from this [site](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete). However `PlaceAutocompleteFragment` is unresolved in my case. How can I fix this issue? I think the solution must be very easy. However I have been looking for quite some time.*

Answer (score 66, accepted):

For uses of `PlaceAutocompleteFragment` we need to add one lib in gradle 
add this

> implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'

in your gradle of Android Application.I have checked this in my Android studio.
Please let me know if your problem is solved.

Check version (16.0.0 at the time of writing) of play-services [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup).
(From the comment below)

Comment: and now it has diverged to `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.4.0'`

Comment: ya and you have to update main app gradle with "classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0''"

Answer (score 3):

Just change your compile library in gradle from "locations" to "places"

for example

change

> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:"yourversion"'

to

> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:"yourversion"'

Answer (score 1):

You need to add one lib in gradle add this

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'
```

use same version "10.0.1" or what you have currenty in your gradle in both services.

Example:-

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

used 
`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'`
but still was facing problem with 'PlaceAutocompleteFragment'

Need to add

`implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0'`